# Get only file names from s3 bucket folder and print on another bucket in text file using glue

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-glue

In glue, we are performing an ETL operation, after giving input files when glue job runs successfully files adding an output bucket so Here we need to write- extra code for copying the output file names and paste in another bucket in a text file

Eg: suppose today 5 files were added to the output bucket so immediately that files names must copy and place in another bucket text file\ with time

can anyone please tell me the solution to this

Comment: Can you include what you've tried so far? And what the error is?

Comment: Hai thanks for the comment
I didn't get any error actually I need to try this
Need code for this